# Count characters in an array of character strings?

Tags: c, string

Given an array of character strings such as...

```
char *example[] = {"s", "ss", "sss"};
```

How can I write a function to count the total number of chars in the array including the terminating characters, without using the standard library for strlen() etc.

Follows is my attempt

```
int countChars(char *array[], int len)
{
    int total = 0, count = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] != NULL)
        {
            while (*array[i] != '\0') {
                count++;
            }
            count++;
        }
        total += count;
    }

    return total;
}
```

An explanation on how char *array[] actually works for access wold be appreciated. I believe that it is supposed to be an array of pointers to strings.

Comment: well, what's your issue? the obvious bug I'm seeing is that you're not resetting `count` between each word

Comment: It seems that `if (array[i] != NULL)` has no meaning.

Comment: Incase the array has had strings removed.

Comment: If you are counting *bytes*, this is easy. If you want to count *characters*, it can get quite involved. (Multi-byte encoding, combining characters, ...)

Answer (score 2):

- You have to increment the index to consider each of the character.

Something like this:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (array[i] != NULL)
    {
        int j=0,count=0;
        while (array[i][j++] != '\0') {
            count++;
        }
        total += count;     
    }

}
```

- Also reset the `count` or add to `total` at the end of all the calculation.

As an answer to your second question:-

---

> `char* array[]` is basically denoting an array pointers each pointing
>   to the string literals with which you initialized it.
>
> So once you use `array[i]` you should now think that it is nothing
>   other than a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: `count` is defined inside if-block.  `total += count;` : Using `count` at out of scope. Also _including the terminating characters_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY.: The answer detects the problem right. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize the variable `count` inside the for loop for each processed string and to increase the expression `*array[i]` inside the while loop.

Also it is better when the function has the return type `size_t` (`size_t` is the type that is returned by the standard C function `strlen` and by the operator `sizeof`)

The function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t countChars( const char *array[], size_t n )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while ( n-- )
    {
        if ( array[n] )
        {
            size_t i = 0;
            do { ++count; } while ( array[n][i++] );
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char * example[] = { "s", "ss", "sss" };

    printf( "%zu\n", countChars( example, sizeof( example ) / sizeof( *example ) ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
9
```

Each element of this array

```
char *example[] = {"s", "ss", "sss"};
```

has type `char *` and is a pointer to the first character of the corresponding string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array contains string constants you should declare it with `const`:

```
const char *example[3];
```

Without `const` the compiler will not warn you if you try to assign a character to *example*[*i*][*j*]. For the same reason the formal parameter should also be declared with `const`.

For a pure function with no side effects it is better to name it so that it reflects the result. Therefor I would use *charCount* instead of *countChars* (or maybe *totalLength*). The focus should be on a *noun* (namely *count* or *length*).

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof (a)[0])

static int CharCount(const char *strings[], int len)
{
    int result, i, j;

    result = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        j = 0;
        while (strings[i][j] != '\0') {
            result++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    const char *strings[] = { "s", "ss", "sss" };

    printf("character count: %d\n", CharCount(strings, LEN(strings)));
}
```

The length macro *LEN* is very convenient and is the least error prone way to handle array lengths.

Answer (score -1):

Yes `char *array[] = {"aa", "bb", "cc"}` is an array of pointers to strings.

- `array[0]` points to `"aa"`
- `array[1]` points to `"bb"`
- `array[2]` points to `"cc"`

You probably want this:

```
int countChars(char *array[], int len)
{
  int count = 0;

  for (int arrayindex = 0; arrayindex < len; arrayindex++)
  {
    const char *stringptr = array[arrayindex];
                                // stringptr will point successively
                                // to "s", to "ss" and to "sss"

    while (*stringptr++)
      count++;                  // increment count until NUL character encountered
    count++;                    // one more for NUL character
  }

  return count;
}

int main() {
  char *example[] = { "s", "ss", "sss" };

  int x = countChars(example, 3);   // x contains 9 after the call to countChars
                                    // that is 2 + 3 + 4
}
```

Instead of hard coding `3` you could use `sizeof(example) / sizeof(example[0])`.